# Problem executing command as a different user with sudo -u

Tags: sudo, su

When I'm trying to execute `ls` as user `abc` with the following command I get an error:

```
xyz@host:~/temp$ sudo -u abc ls
[sudo] password for xyz:
Sorry, user xyz is not allowed to execute '/bin/ls' as abc on host.
```

But if I do `su abc` and then execute `ls` I have no problem

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should configure `sudo` security policy to allow user `xyz` to execute something as user `abc`. Read the `sudoers` manual (`man sudoers`) and use the `visudo` command to configure `/etc/sudoers`.

For example, let's allow user `xyz` to execute `/usr/bin/whoami` as user `abc` without a password. Add this string into `/etc/sudoers` (with `visudo`, don't edit `/etc/sudoers` directly):

```
xyz ALL = (abc) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/whoami
```

And now, test it:

```
xyz@host:~$ sudo -u abc /usr/bin/whoami
abc
```

Comment: did you mind explain why should avoid edit /etc/sudoers directly?

Comment: Because when you edit /etc/sudoers directly you can make a mistake, broke the sudoers file and (in worst scenario) block yourself with using sudo. 'Visudo' is not just an editor, it also checks the syntax of the sudoers file and helps to avoid mistakes, typos etc.

Answer (score 4):

This is because `sudo` is different from `su`. When you `su abc`, you become the user `abc` as far as the system is concerned. You can then do anything that `abc` can do.

On the other hand, `sudo` is used to allow other users to execute some commands by proxy. In other words, your `sudo` configuration allows you to do some commands on behalf of `abc`. If the command you're trying to execute is not one of them, you get the error you reported.

Answer (score 0):

In case everything is looking alright, but you still get `Sorry user xxx cannot execute...` message and it keeps asking you for a `sudo` password everytime.

You can do this:

1. In `/etc/sudoers` delete line with your user settings
2. Save file
3. Open file, type (NO COPING) your options for that user
4. Save file
5. Try it.

This worked for me. It turned out that the ending in that line was bad because I copied commands that needed execution from email.

Comment: Surely if you had used `visudo` to edit it in the first place, you'd have been told that?

Comment: Nop, you wouldn't.

Comment: Ah, well. I really would have thought...  In any case, I think you are far more likely to get errors manually typing than from copy and paste. Just be aware that line-ends differ.